# Injection error: Cannot resolve all parameters

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error when trying to inject the `Http` service into my `PanelsService`.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

export class PanelsService {

  constructor(public http:Http) { }

  getPanelFilters() {
    var url = '../../data/panelFilters/' + 13677 + '.json'

    return this.http.get(url)
  }

}
```

I'm attempting to access the `PanelsService` from my `SidebarComponent`:

```
import {PanelsService} from '../panels/panels.service';

@Component({
  ....
  providers: [PanelsService]
})

export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public panelsService:PanelsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('I am the sidebar component');
  }

}
```

It should be noted that my `tsconfig.json` also has the lines:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

I've tried using `@Injectable` as demonstrated [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) but  when I decorate my class with `@Injectable()` I get an error in the console:

[image]

`boot.js` simply bootstraps my app component, it doesn't inject any dependencies:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to include the http bundle in your script tags.

Comment: @EricMartinez Just realized that - thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's one thing missing in your code: Providers.

With

```
export class PanelsService {

  constructor(public http:Http) { }
}
```

You ask for a dependency that the injector identifies with the token `Http` (the type annotation). However, there's nothing in your code (at least as shown here), that tells your injector **what** it has to return for the token `Http`. So it's just half of the information.

In order to resolve a dependency we need a token (the thing we're asking for) and a provider (the thing that creates that object we're asking for). Provider can be configured either during `bootstrap()` or at component level using the `providers` property in the `@Component()` decorator.

Unless you want to create a new instance of `Http` every time, it makes most sense to configure that provider at `bootstrap()` to make the same instance available throughout your entire application.

Here's what a provider for `Http` could look like:

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(YourApp, [
  provide(Http, {useClass: Http})
]);
```

`provide()` takes a token `Http` and configures a provider with a recipe that describes how to create an object of something (`useClass: Http`). If the recipe is `useClass` and the class is the same as the token, we can use the following shorthand syntax:

```
bootstrap(YourApp, [
  Http
]);
```

However, we'll realise that this is not enough, since it turns out that `Http` uses DI itself for its own dependencies too. Which means, we need providers for those dependencies as well. Luckily, for these cases Angular already provides a predefined list of providers.

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` is a collection of provider configurations that are needed to make `Http` work. So all you have to do is:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(YourApp, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Now your app knows about all dependencies, tokens and providers for anything `Http`.

You can find a more detailed explanation in this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks. I had actually read that article and a few others on thoughtgram but came away pretty confused and unsure if I should be using `resolveAndCreate` everywhere. Your explanation was much clearer.

Comment: Notice that the `provide` function is deprecated; now accepts an object with a `provide` **property** and a `useClass` property [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38341311/1175496)