# Angular2's provide() function deprecated in RC4 and later, what should be used instead?

Tags: angular, deprecated, provider

I just upgraded from Angular2 RC1 to RC4.

Before I used:

```
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
```

However, after upgraded to RC4, the provide shows as deprecated.

I did not find any documentation on this.

Does anyone have an idea about what happened?

Comment: could you show where the import is that is bringing in the provide?

Comment: Use map literal `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How did you find this? Thanks!

Comment: just found this on their documents. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#provide

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments above, you should now just use an object with `provide` and `useClass` properties, such as in the following:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    CookieService,
    AuthService,
    WindowService,
    COMMON_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provideRouter(AppRoutes),
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
]);
```

This example is from my Github [project using Angular2, Bootstrap 4, OAuth2, and Webpack](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack).  I've been updating it as the various alpha, beta, and RC releases of Angular2 have been put out.

Comment: How to inject mock service in a test suit?

Comment: under `providers` using  `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [ .. ]  })` same way as here